# removing current _POST data to submit form to new page

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I have a form where I would like to use `_POST` data to submit check box values. My problem is there are already post values in my current page. When I submit the form it is returning the current post values instead of the ones I want, which gives me the `Notice: Undefined index` message.

Basically this form is to compare selected products, but in the current post values it has the product information along with order by values. Is there a way to just submit my new form's information on its own?

Thank you

**EDIT**

Well, here's the thing about my code, I am using a shopping cart called Virtuemart. I've added the code below minus all the other stuff which don't effect the form.

**Product File**

```
 // Code here for Template file for individual items in category
    //creating checkbox for comparison form
    echo "<input type =\"checkbox\" name=\"fruit[]\" value=\"".$product_sku."\" />
    <label for=\"".$product_name."\"> ".$product_name."</label>";
```

**Category File**

```
//all other forms on this page 
<form action="items/index.php" method="get" name="results" target="_blank">
<input class="inputbox" name="search" id="item-search" type="text" value="Search"></td><td>
<input type="image" class="sub-button" src="/search.png" alt="submit" name="submit" value="search">
</form>


<form action="index.php" method="get" name="order">
Sort by:
<select class="inputbox" name="orderby" onchange="order.submit()">
<option value="product_list" >Select</option>
        <option value="product_name" selected="selected">Product Name</option>
        <option value="product_price" >Price</option>
        <option value="product_cdate" >Latest Products</option>
        </select>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
            document.write('&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="DescOrderBy" value="ASC" /><a href="javascript: document.order.DescOrderBy.value=\'DESC\'; document.order.submit()"><img src="images/sort_asc.png" border="0" alt="Ascending order" title="Ascending order" width="12" height="12" /></a>');
            //]]></script>
<noscript>
        <select class="inputbox" name="DescOrderBy">
        <option  value="DESC">Descending order</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="ASC">Ascending order</option>
        </select>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </noscript>
    <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="89" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="shop.browse" />
    <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="manufacturer_id" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="keyword" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="keyword1" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="keyword2" value="" />

<div id='limitbox'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Display #&nbsp;&nbsp;

<select class="inputbox-reg" name="limit" size="1"  onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option value="6" >6</option>
<option value="18" >18</option>
<option value="30" >30</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="limitstart" value="0" /></div>   <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></noscript> 
    <!-- PAGE NAVIGATION AT THE TOP <br/>
    <div style="text-align:center;">    </div>
    -->
</form>

// all other forms end
```

**Form I want to pass values from**

```
echo"<form method=\"POST\" name=\"compare\" id=\"compare\" action=\"http://localhost/comparepage/\">";

//TEMPLATE FILE HERE THAT GENERATE PRODUCTS FROM PRODUCT FILE CODE ABOVE.
//Basically it has foreach statements to generate all products

echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Compare\" onClick=\"document.compare.submit()\" >";

echo "</form>";
```

I've changed `POST` to `GET` just to get the values that are being passed and in the next page I see a bunch of values in the url.

Comment: Confused ! Can you post your code here ?

Comment: Add some code. It's hard to guess what you tried

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the fields of the second form within separate <form> tags

Form 1:

```
<form method='post' action='/process.php'>
    <input name='town' type='text'/>
    <input name='country' type='text'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

Form 2:

```
<form method='post' action='/process.php'>
    <input name='gender' type='text'/>
    <input name='state' type='text'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

If you submit form 1, $_POST will contain town, country
If you submit form 2, $_POST will contain gender & state

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, some code and more details would be helpful. But if you have multiple form fields on the same page, and depending on the action, you want to submit different sets of those fields, then just wrap them in different `<form></form>` elements. A POST submit only submits the form fields contained with that particular  block.

So you could have:

```
<form name='form1' method='POST' action='#'>
   <input type='hidden' name='field1' value='true' />
   <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
<form name='form2' method='POST' action='#'>
   <input type='hidden' name='field1' value='false' />
   <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

If the first submit button is clicked, `$_POST['field1'] = 'true', else = 'false'`